# Typegoose/ Mongoose nested discriminator is not accepting array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am building a Node application using TypeScript and MongoDB as my application's database. I am using Typegoose to interact with MongoDB from Node JS application. Now, I am having a problem with using Nested Discriminator, https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/nested-discriminators/ in my application.

I have a model called Workflow with the following code.

```
export class Workflow {
  @prop({ required: true, type: Date, default: new Date() })
  public createdAt!: Date;

  @prop({ required: true, type: () => [WorkflowTask] })
  public tasks!: WorkflowTask[];
}

export const WorkflowModel = getModelForClass(Workflow);
```

As you can see, a workflow can have many tasks (WorkflowTask). Below is the dummy code of my WorkflowTask model.

```
export class WorkflowTask {
  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public title?: string;

  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public description?: string;

  @prop({ required: true, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public type!: WorkflowTaskType;

  @prop({
    required: true,
    type: FormContent,
    discriminators: () => [
      {
        type: TextFormFieldContent,
        value: FormWorkflowTaskContentType.TEXT_FORM_FIELD
      },
      {
        type: NumberFormFieldContent,
        value: FormWorkflowTaskContentType.NUMBER_FORM_FIELD
      }
    ],
    default: []
  })
  public formContents!: FormContent[];
}
```

As you can see, a WorkflowTask can have many FormContent where I put the discriminator in.

The following are some dummy code for my Workflow content classes.

```
export class FormContent {
  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public label?: string;

  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public message?: string;

  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public description?: string;

  @prop({ required: true, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public type!: FormWorkflowTaskContentType;
}

export class TextFormFieldContent extends FormContent {
  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public defaultValue?: string;
}

export class EmailFormFieldContent extends FormContent {
  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public defaultValue?: string;
}

export class NumberFormFieldContent extends FormContent {
  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.String })
  public defaultValue?: string;
}

export class MultiSelectFieldContent extends FormContent {
  @prop({ required: false, type: Schema.Types.Array, default: [] })
  public defaultValue?: string[];
}
```

At the moment, I am only trying to create a workflow with empty tasks using the following code.

```
  await WorkflowModel.create({
    createdAt: new Date(),
    tasks: []
  });
```

I am getting the following error when I run the code.

```
ValidationError: Workflow validation failed: tasks: Cast to Embedded failed for value "[]" (type Array) at path "tasks" because of "ObjectExpectedError"
```

I am not even populating the tasks for the workflow. I followed the page correctly. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: what versions of typescript, typegoose and mongoose are being used? also are there any warnings from typegoose?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the typegoose documentation for the [`type` option of the `@prop` decorator](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop#type) it seems like the `type` you pass should be the type of the array's items:

> Example: Arrays (array item types can't be automatically inferred via Reflect)
>
> ```
> class Dummy {
>   @prop({ type: String })
>   public hello: string[];
> }
> ```

If that's the case the decorator may be defined as:

```
  @prop({ required: true, type: () => WorkflowTask })
  public tasks!: WorkflowTask[];
```

or

```
  @prop({ required: true, type: WorkflowTask })
  public tasks!: WorkflowTask[];
```

Comment: actually, since typegoose 7.4.0, arrays can be defined with `type: [Type]` (or the type-graphql way of defining types), at the same time depending on how many arrays are used, it will define the `dim` option https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop#dim (zero and one of `[]` are equal to `dim: 1`)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything obviously wrong with your provided code, and i also locally tried to test your code which was working just fine.

Reproduction Repository / Branch: https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose-testing/tree/SO74916118

But there are some notes:

- you can improve readability by replacing `Schema.Types.String` with `String`, typegoose & mongoose will automatically translate it to the proper Schema-Type
- `type: Schema.Types.Array` is likely not what you want to set, this will effectively be of the `Mixed` type, in this case `String` would be appropiate
- `default: new Date()` is likely not what you want, you probably want to change it to `default: () => new Date()`, the way it is currently defined evaluates `default: new Date()` at the time of loading the file once instead of everytime a document is created
- some values were not provided and have been inferred in the reproduction code (not provided were `FormWorkflowTaskContentType` and `WorkflowTaskType`)

---

PS: another answer has pointed out that `type: () => [WorkflowTask]` is not supported, which is not true; the syntax of `type: [Type]` is supported since typegoose 7.4.0

---

Slight Note:
if you code fails, you may just be on old versions or you are running into [Circular Dependencies](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/reference-other-classes#circular-dependencies)

Comment: I used `type: () => [WorkflowTask]` but it still does not work.

Comment: please provide more information on what still does not work, because from my testing (in the mentioned repository & branch), everything was working correctly

Comment: It is this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981428/mongodb-typegoose-is-throwing-error-tried-to-set-nested-object-field-field-to?noredirect=1.
I am sure you have already seen it.